# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ArrayBuffer | SharedArrayBuffer | ArrayLike<number>'

Tags: angular, typescript

Trying to validate mime type

Error from VScode: ERROR in src/app/posts/post-create/mimie-type.validator.ts(12,36): error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArrayBuffer | SharedArrayBuffer | ArrayLike'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ArrayBuffer | SharedArrayBuffer | ArrayLike'.

Issue is on line 12 with fileReader.result.... not sure exactly where I went wrong in the code. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable, Observer } from 'rxjs';

export const mimeType = (
  control: AbstractControl
): Promise<{ [key: string]: any }> | Observable<{ [key: string]: any }> => {
  const file = control.value as File;
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  const frObs = Observable.create(
    (observer: Observer<{ [key: string]: any }>) => {
      fileReader.addEventListener('loadend', () => {
        const arr = new Uint8Array(fileReader.result).subarray(0, 4);
        let header = '';
        let isValid = false;
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          header += arr[i].toString(16);
        }
        switch (header) {
          case '89504e47':
            isValid = true;
            break;
          case 'ffd8ffe0':
          case 'ffd8ffe1':
          case 'ffd8ffe2':
          case 'ffd8ffe3':
          case 'ffd8ffe8':
            isValid = true;
            break;
          default:
            isValid = false; // Or you can use the blob.type as fallback
            break;
        }
        if (isValid) {
          observer.next(null);
        } else {
          observer.next({ invalidMimeType: true });
        }
        observer.complete();
      });
      fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }
  );
  return frObs;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fileReader.result` is of type `string | ArrayBuffer` which means it can be a `string` or `ArrayBuffer` depending on which method you call to read the file. The constructor for `Uint8Array` can only accept an `ArrayBuffer` that is why you get the error since for the compiler the result can also be a `string`.
The easy solution is to just say I know this will be an `ArrayBuffer` by casting it like this:

```
const arr = new Uint8Array(fileReader.result as ArrayBuffer).subarray(0, 4);
```

The better solution is to validate that the result is actually of the type you expect first and then the compiler will not complain because it knows it is of the correct type.

```
if (fileReader.result instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
  const arr = new Uint8Array(fileReader.result).subarray(0, 4);
  // the rest of your code
} else {
  throw new Error('Unexpected result');
}
```